# Good reference for SQL to use with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had been working on Oracle long time back and has exposure to SQL. Now I need to brush up my SQL skills for a project on SQL Server 2008. Could you please recommend a good resource (online/book)?

Comment: What role? e.g. if you were writing C#.NET code then I might suggest looking at Entity Framework as an alternative to writing SQL; if a tester code-reviewing (but not writing) stored procs then I'd suggest something entirely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "books online" help isn't too bad for SQL2008 i.e. usually several examples, shows the syntax clearly. You can download it separately.

Comment: Link for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here are three great books, if you could buy only one and wanted a reference I'd recommend the first

SQL Server 2008 Internals
[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft%C2%AE-SQL-Server%C2%AE-2008-Internals/dp/0735626243/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1330914927&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626243)

2008: T-SQL Programming
[http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Microsoft%C2%AE-Server%C2%AE-2008-Pro-Developer/dp/0735626022/ref=pd_bxgy_b_text_b](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626022)

2008: T-SQL Querying
[http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Microsoft%C2%AE-SQL-Server%C2%AE-2008/dp/0735626030/ref=pd_bxgy_b_text_c](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626030)